# Search through object using where cluse in mongodb an node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hey guys please I need help I have a table in mongodb that contains an object and am trying to make a search query where the input data is = a data inside the object, but am having a syntax error how do I fix this please

*My code*

```
router.post('/',async(req,red)=>{
const getData = await Database.findOne({school.dept:req.body})
res.Json(Database)
})
```

**How my table looks like**

```
_id: object(628gs45hhd45)
email: email.com
school:{
 dept: elementary
 course: atomic bomb
}
age: 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving this error because `school.dept` need to inside quotes like this

```
const getData = await Database.findOne({'school.dept':req.body})
```

MongoDB playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HrPYA240hqv)